# Apps that are offered in Newsstand must comply with schedules 1, 2

Tags: ios, objective-c

How to resolve this issue :: "Apps that are offered in Newsstand must comply with schedules 1, 2 and 3 of the Developer Program License Agreement or they will be rejected"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are really strict on these kind of Agreements. You can find them here: https://developer.apple.com/programs/terms/registered_apple_developer_20100301.pdf

Comment: Thanks peter. This link is very usefull my app